# Type of the datepicker in ant design is not a string when use with getFieldDecorator

Tags: reactjs, validation, datepicker, antd

When I used DatePicker in react.js inside a form with getFieldDecorator, once I  selected a date it will give an error saying "datepicker value is not a string."

I tried datepicker without form's getFieldDecorator where it will not displaying an error. But I need to use DatePicker with getFieldDecorator.

```
<FormItem
                {...formItemLayout}
                label="Start Date"
            >
                {getFieldDecorator('startValue', {
                    rules: [{
                        message: 'The input is not a valid Start Date!'
                    }, {
                        required: true, message: 'Please input your Starting Date for the assigned task',
                    }],
                })(
                    <DatePicker
                        disabledDate={this.disabledStartDate}
                        showTime
                        format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
                        placeholder="Start"
                        onChange={this.onStartChange}
                        onOpenChange={this.handleStartOpenChange}
                    />
                )}
</FormItem>
```

Above is the part of the code for datepicker. There I always getting an error saying The input is not a valid Start Date! (In console it's saying not a string.) So how can I get resolved from this error?

Comment: `DatePicker` expects value to be `moment` instance

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this part from validation rules:

```
{
    message: 'The input is not a valid Start Date!'
}
```

You can check the [validation rules of ant-design](https://ant.design/components/form/#Validation-Rules). I have created a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wy8nm0nnl7).

Answer (score 0):

```
        <FormItem {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}>
          {getFieldDecorator("startValue", {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please input your Starting Date for the assigned task"
              }
            ]
          })(
            <DatePicker
              disabledDate={this.disabledStartDate}
              showTime
              format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
              placeholder="Start"
              onChange={this.onStartChange}
              onOpenChange={this.handleStartOpenChange}
            />
          )}
        </FormItem>
```